# Adding two n and m bit binary numbers

Tags: algorithm, c, bitwise, bitset

Recently I was studying bitwise operators and bit-manipulation algorithms and I found out an algorithm to add two binary numbers.

Pseudocode is as follows:

```
function add(A, B):
    while B is greater than 0:
        U = A XOR B, where XOR = Bitwise XOR of A and B.
        V = A AND B, where AND = Bitwise AND of A and B.
        A = U
        B = V * 2, this instruction is equivalent to V << 1
    return A
```

`A` and `B` are bit strings of length `N` and `M` where the limits for `N` and `M` are: 0 < N <= 10^5 and 0 < M <= 10^5. Both the bit strings can be of different lengths.

I was wondering about finding out how many times the `while` loop runs before the `B = 0`.

Problem Statement:

> How many times does the `while` loop run before `B = 0`?

I wrote an algorithm in C which takes two strings `A` and `B` as input. If the length of both the strings is not same then first make them same, then perform bitwise XOR and bitwise AND and bitwise left-shift to implement multiplication by `2` as described in the above algorithm.

**Source code is as follows:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<inttypes.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<assert.h>

#define STRING_LENGTH_MAX 100001

static const uint64_t binary_to_decimal(char[*]);
static const uint64_t binary_exponentiation(uint64_t,uint64_t);
static const uint32_t binary_addition_integers(uint64_t,uint64_t);
static char* make_string_equal(char[*],uint32_t);
static const bool check_all_zeroes(char[*]);
static const uint32_t binary_addition_strings(char[*],char[*]);
static char* bitwise_xor_strings(char[*],char[*]);
static char* bitwise_and_strings(char[*],char[*]);
static char* bitwise_left_shift_by_one_strings(char[*]);

int main(void) {
    int32_t test;
    printf("Enter the number of test-cases\n");
    scanf("%"SCNd32, &test);
    assert(test > 0 && test < 100001);
    while(test--) {
        char *binary_string_A = calloc(STRING_LENGTH_MAX,sizeof(char));
        char *binary_string_B = calloc(STRING_LENGTH_MAX,sizeof(char));
        printf("Enter the bit-strings A and B\n");
        scanf("%s%s", binary_string_A,binary_string_B);
        uint32_t len_binary_string_A = strlen(binary_string_A);
        uint32_t len_binary_string_B = strlen(binary_string_B);
        uint32_t loop_count = 0;
        if(len_binary_string_A < 63 && len_binary_string_B < 63) {
            uint64_t a = binary_to_decimal(binary_string_A);
            uint64_t b = binary_to_decimal(binary_string_B);
            if(!b) {
                loop_count = 0;
            } else if(!a) {
                loop_count = 1;
            } else if(a == b) {
                loop_count = 2;
            } else {
                loop_count = binary_addition_integers(a,b);
            }
        } else {
            if(len_binary_string_A < len_binary_string_B) {
                binary_string_A = make_string_equal(binary_string_A,len_binary_string_B);
                if(!binary_string_A) {
                    fprintf(stderr,"Line number: %u: Not able to allocate the memory to *binary_string_A\n", __LINE__);
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
            } else {
                binary_string_B = make_string_equal(binary_string_B,len_binary_string_A);
                if(!binary_string_B) {
                    fprintf(stderr,"Line number: %u: Not able to allocate memory to *binary_string_B\n", __LINE__);
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
            }
            if(check_all_zeroes(binary_string_B)) {
                loop_count = 0;
            } else if(check_all_zeroes(binary_string_A)) {
                loop_count = 1;
            } else if(!strncmp(binary_string_A,binary_string_B,strlen(binary_string_A))) {
                loop_count = 2;
            } else {
                loop_count = binary_addition_strings(binary_string_A,binary_string_B);
            }
        }
        free(binary_string_A);
        free(binary_string_B);
        printf("Loop-Runs: %"PRIu32"\n", loop_count);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

static const uint64_t binary_to_decimal(char binary_string[]) {
    uint32_t string_len = strlen(binary_string);
    uint64_t decimal_value = 0;
    for(int8_t i = (string_len - 1), power = 0; i >= 0; --i,++power) {
        if(!(binary_string[i] == '0')) {
            if(i == (string_len - 1)) {
                decimal_value += binary_string[i] - '0';
            } else {
                decimal_value += (binary_string[i] - '0') * binary_exponentiation(2,power);
            }
        }
    }
    return decimal_value;
}

static const uint64_t binary_exponentiation(uint64_t base,uint64_t expo) {
    uint64_t result = 1;
    if(!expo) {
        return result;
    } else if(expo == 1) {
        return base;
    } else {
        while(expo) {
            if(expo & 1) {
                result *= base;
            }
            base *= base;
            expo >>= 1;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

static const uint32_t binary_addition_integers(uint64_t a,uint64_t b) {
    uint32_t loop_count = 0;
    while(b) {
        ++loop_count;
        uint64_t x = a ^ b;
        uint64_t y = a & b;
        a = x;
        b = y << 1;
    }
    return loop_count;
}

static char* make_string_equal(char binary_string[],uint32_t target_len) {
    uint32_t prev_len = strlen(binary_string);
    binary_string = realloc(binary_string,(sizeof(char) * (target_len + 1)));
    if(binary_string) {
        for(int32_t i = (prev_len - 1), j = (target_len - 1); i >= 0; --i,--j) {
            binary_string[j] = binary_string[i];
        }
        uint32_t limit = target_len - prev_len;
        for(uint32_t i = 0; i < limit; ++i) {
            binary_string[i] = '0';
        }
        binary_string[target_len] = '\0';
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr,"Line number: %u: Not able to re-allocate %lu bytes of memory\n", __LINE__,(sizeof(char) * target_len));
        return NULL;
    }
    return binary_string;
}

static const bool check_all_zeroes(char binary_string[]) {
    bool is_all_zeroes = true;
    for(uint32_t i = 0; binary_string[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        if(binary_string[i] != '0') {
            is_all_zeroes = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return is_all_zeroes;
}

static const uint32_t binary_addition_strings(char *binary_string_A,char *binary_string_B) {
    uint32_t loop_count = 0;
    while(!check_all_zeroes(binary_string_B)) {
        ++loop_count;
        char *binary_string_X = bitwise_xor_strings(binary_string_A,binary_string_B);
        char *binary_string_Y = bitwise_and_strings(binary_string_A,binary_string_B);
        binary_string_A = binary_string_X;
        binary_string_B = bitwise_left_shift_by_one_strings(binary_string_Y);
        binary_string_A = make_string_equal(binary_string_A,strlen(binary_string_B));
    }
    return loop_count;
}

static char* bitwise_xor_strings(char binary_string_A[],char binary_string_B[]) {
    uint32_t xor_result_len = strlen(binary_string_A) + 1;
    char *xor_result = calloc(xor_result_len,sizeof(char));
    if(xor_result) {
        for(int32_t i = (xor_result_len - 2); i >= 0; --i) {
            xor_result[i] = ((binary_string_A[i] - '0') ^ (binary_string_B[i] - '0')) + '0';
        }
        xor_result[xor_result_len - 1] = '\0';
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr,"Line number: %u: Not able to allocate %lu bytes of memory to *xor_result\n", __LINE__,(sizeof(char) * xor_result_len));
        xor_result = NULL;
    }
    return xor_result;
}

static char* bitwise_and_strings(char binary_string_A[],char binary_string_B[]) {
    uint32_t and_result_len =  strlen(binary_string_A) + 1;
    char *and_result = calloc(and_result_len,sizeof(char));
    if(and_result) {
        for(int32_t i = (and_result_len - 2); i >= 0; --i) {
            and_result[i] = ((binary_string_A[i] - '0') & (binary_string_B[i] - '0')) + '0';
        }
        and_result[and_result_len - 1] = '\0';
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr,"Line number: %u: Not able to allocate %lu bytes of memory to *and_result\n", __LINE__,(sizeof(char) * and_result_len));
        and_result = NULL;
    }
    return and_result;
}

static char* bitwise_left_shift_by_one_strings(char binary_string[]) {
    uint32_t bitwise_left_shift_by_one_result_len = strlen(binary_string) + 2;
    char *bitwise_left_shift_by_one_result = realloc(binary_string,(sizeof(char) * bitwise_left_shift_by_one_result_len));
    if(bitwise_left_shift_by_one_result) {
        bitwise_left_shift_by_one_result[bitwise_left_shift_by_one_result_len - 2] = '0';
        bitwise_left_shift_by_one_result[bitwise_left_shift_by_one_result_len - 1] = '\0';
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr,"Line number: %u: Not able to re-allocate memory block to *bitwise_left_shift_by_one_result\n", __LINE__);
        bitwise_left_shift_by_one_result = NULL;
    }
    return bitwise_left_shift_by_one_result;
}
```

**Program Output:**

```
Enter the number of test-cases
4
Enter the bit-strings A and B
100010
0
Loop-Runs: 0
Enter the bit-strings A and B
0
100010
Loop-Runs: 1
Enter the bit-strings A and B
11100
1010
Loop-Runs: 3
Enter the bit-strings A and B
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
Loop-Runs: 10
```

As you can see the algorithm which I come up with does execute all the steps in order to find out the answer i.e. loop count, but as I am only interested in how many times the loop runs and if there are any other way of finding that value.

How can I optimize the code if the number of bits in the binary numbers is > 500? 
What I did was if the number of bits in the given binary numbers `A` and `B` <= 63, I find their decimal equivalent and use the bitwise operators defined in C, but as you know if the length of the string becomes > 64 its decimal equivalent cannot be stored in a normal 64-bit unsigned integer in C/C++. So I just implemented the above algorithm on bit strings without finding their decimal equivalent but the algorithm which I designed is not fast enough if n > 500 so, can you tell how can I optimize my code.

However, I can use the following Python code to accomplish the task:

```py
def binary_addition(a,b):
    loop_count = 0
    while b != 0:
        loop_count += 1
        x = a ^ b
        y = a & b
        a = x
        b = y << 1
    return loop_count

def main():
    test = int(input())
    for t in range(test):
        a = int('0b' + input().rstrip(),base = 2)
        b = int('0b' + input().rstrip(),base = 2)
        if not b:
            print("0")
        elif not a:
            print("1")
        elif a == b:
            print("2")
        else:
            print(binary_addition(a,b))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I think the first usual optimization would be to do it one bit at a time, propagating the carry.  This changes an O(n^2) operation into an O(n) operation.  The you can group the bits into larger integer values, and if desired use the + operator, still keeping track of the carry.

Comment: So, can I say that the total number of times the `while` loop runs is equal to number of times carry is generated? In the question I need to find out how many times the `while` loop runs, and the above implementation takes `(O(n) for XOR + O(n) for AND + O(n) for Left shift by one) * Number of times while loop executes` in worst-case. Can I do better?

Comment: If you try to add (2^n)-1 and 1, the loop will run n times.  If you really want to optimize, there really is only one good solution:  write in assembly.  There are machine instructions specifically designed for this that aren't exposed in higher level languages.  (Although if you are using python, they already have done the work for you.)

Comment: I think the total number of loops is size of the largest chain of carrys.  This actually is an issue in hardware design.  There is something called (I think) a "fast carry" (that I never got the details of) that is supposed to speed up a large adder.  This supplements a chain of full adders to get the result faster.

Comment: @DavidG. So, programmatically, I cannot find the number of loop counts without doing all the above operations? You are telling about `Largest Chain of Carrys`, can you elaborate on that more? How the concept of `Largest Chain of Carrys` can help me?

Comment: @DavidG. In the problem description, the number of bits in a binary number has an upper bound of `10^5`, that's why I was thinking about optimization of the above code in higher-level only not at the machine level. As I have written the code in `C` which is more close to the hardware, you can tell me some substitutes for the functions which I have used in the program above.

Comment: SurajSharma, Why is `binary_to_decimal()` named with "decimal"?  There is nothing base-10 about it.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Because `binary_to_decimal()` function is returning the decimal representation of the binary-string if length of string is `< 64`.

Comment: Does the C code compile for you? If you run the code does it give you the expected answers?

Comment: @pacmaninbw Yes it does.

Comment: OK.  The performance issue probably becomes most obvious when you add (2^99999-1) and 1.  I would expect that to take about 10^10 loops overall with this algorithm.  The trick to taking only 10^5 loops is to, at each bit position, sum the A bit, the B bit, and the carry from the previous bit.  The output is the result for this bit, and the carry to the next.  Note that this may make an O(n) that is slower than your O(n^2) for small n, simply because it has a larger constant factor.

Comment: @DavidG. Can you write in brief about your idea, will be helpful for me?

Comment: @Suraj: At this point, maybe a reference:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)#Full_adder

Comment: According to Norton Security the link where you pointed me to is a bad website to use.

Comment: @pacmaninbw ok, You can refer to the this: https://pastebin.com/tDnkkDWE

Comment: Re: [function is returning the decimal representation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/234050/how-can-i-optimise-the-algorithm-of-adding-two-n-and-m-bit-binary-numbers?noredirect=1#comment457757_234050) `uint64_t binary_to_decimal(char binary_string[])` returns a integer of type `uint64_t`, not a decimal representation.

Comment: In response to your question about program structure you this is a good starting point that has additional references https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162889/what-methods-are-there-to-modularize-c-code.

Answer (score 2):

The `static` declaration of each of the functions is good, especially if the code is merged into a larger program.

### Error Checking

When using any memory allocation function such as `calloc(size_t number_of_items, size_t size_of_item)`, the return value should be checked to see if it `NULL`. If the function fails it returns `NULL`. Accessing memory through a null pointer results in unknown behavior. The program could crash or corrupt the data in the program.

While the code is performing error checking on the first `scanf` which reads the number of tests, the input from the second `scanf` is not checked. This may lead to errors in the processing of the strings.

### Magic Numbers

The assert that follows the first `scanf` contains the number `100001`. It isn't clear in the program why the maximum number of tests is `100001`. There is a symbolic constant for this number defined (`STRING_LENGTH_MAX`) but the maximum length of the strings shouldn't have anything to do with the maximum number of test cases.

### Complexity

Most of the functions are a reasonable size and complexity, but the function `main()` is too complex (does too much). As programs grow in size, the use of `main()` should be limited to calling functions that parse the command line, calling functions that set up for processing, calling functions that execute the desired function of the program, and calling functions to clean up after the main portion of the program.

There is also a programming principle called the Single Responsibility Principle that applies here. The [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) states:

> that every module, class, or function should have responsibility over a single part of the functionality provided by the software, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by that module, class or function.

The contents of the `while(test--)` loop should be in its own function, and that function should probably be broken up into 2 or 3 functions as well.

Smaller functions are easier to write, debug, read and maintain. In some instances they may be reused as well.

### Use the Native Word Size of the Processor

The native word size of the processor will provide the best performance when the code is executing. Using a smaller sized word can slow down the processing; most processors today have a word size of 64 bits, so forcing `uint32_t` may be counter-productive. If the variable should be unsigned, just use the type declaration `unsigned`; if the variable can take on negative values use `int`. This code doesn't need to use smaller word sizes.

The repeated use of `calloc()` may slow down the program.  It might be better to use arrays rather than allocated memory.

### Possible Program Structure

As C programs get larger, it becomes necessary to break files up by function into modules. Most of the functions in this program can be moved into another C file, with a header file providing the public interfaces. In this case, there would be one public interface called by `main()` which would be the execution of each test case (suggested above, but not yet written). This would remove all of the function prototypes at the top of the file.

Comment: "most processors today have a word size of 64 bits" --> Disagree, billion of processors per year now are now embedded ones, with 32 bit and smaller dominating.

Comment: The points related to Possible Program Structure, actually I have never built a C program by breaking it into modules. Can you guide me to a reference where I can learn about software development in C especially what should be the file structure `src/ modules/ libraries/ etc` how to declare variables, when to use `extern` variables. It's a broad question, I just need some online references to get started. Moreover thanks for the answer, I will made this changes but however these changes are not going to improve the time-complexity of the algorithm by a significant amount.

Comment: About the Magic Number point, that was the constraint given in the problem statement i.e `1 <= number of bits <= 10^5`. As in C programming, stri ngs are terminated by `\0` character, hence the Magic Number `100001`.

Comment: How would the repeated use of `calloc()` function will make program slower?

Comment: The syntax which I used for declaring functions are correct and my program gets successfully compiled through `gcc` compiler and executes as intended on Ubuntu Linux 18.04 LTS. Actually I have read in a reddit post that `[*]` syntax is used for the declaration of Variable Length Arrays when passing into function.

Comment: The [*] syntax is valid but deprecated (or will already be removed?) in C2x

Comment: @pacmaninbw I am dynamically allocating the memory using `calloc()` because when the program executes the logic of addition, the program need both the bit-strings of same size and if they are not of not, then program re-size the string returns the base-address. that's why I used `calloc()` because if I use static arrays then I cannot resize the array dynamically.

Comment: "There are a number of syntax errors if you are using a strict C compiler; the following function prototypes don't compile using a compiler that really follows the C programming standard" This is completely wrong. If you don't know the standard well, you should compile with strict settings before making such claims. It's clear that you aren't aware of the exotic [*] syntax that's been standard for 20 years. It declares an array parameter of incomplete type, that has to be completed upon function definition. Completely useless feature but perfectly valid C.

Comment: @larkey Who says it is deprecated? Not C17 "future language directions".

Comment: @Lundin I just looked it up and it wasn't deprecated but there's movement in the WG to remove it. I thought they'd already voted on it, but apparently they didn't.

Comment: @Lundin I have removed the section you found offensive.

Comment: @larkey I have removed the [*] syntax section.

Comment: It would be valid to remark about using qualifiers on return types though, since that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @SurajSharma Why does the program tie the number of test cases to the number of bits?

Comment: Because I have a test file name `test-case-1.in` which consists of multiple inputs. For E.g. https://pastebin.com/HY86ubdg

Comment: @SurajSharma this is what my comment about Magic numbers was about. There is no clear reason in the code why the number is 10001. This makes the code hard for anyone to maintain. When you code you need to keep in mind that other people may need to maintain the code.

Comment: @pacmaninbw The magic number is basically the maximum length of the bit-string.

Answer (score 2):

> how can I can make my C code better & efficient.

Simplification for `binary_to_decimal()`

```
// static const uint64_t binary_to_decimal(char binary_string[]) {
static uint64_t binary_to_uint64(const char *binary_string) {
  uint64_t value = 0;
  while (*binary_string >= '0' && *binary_string <= '1') {
    value = value*2 + (*binary_string++ - '0');
  }
  return value;
}
```

Now `binary_exponentiation()` is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks to all the answers, I learned something new from all those answers.

Now coming back to the problem-statement, as no answer gave me an exact way of solving the problem in an efficient manner, so I did some research about the way the binary addition is performed, and I found that the algorithm described is known as **No-Carry Adder** in digital-logic, and the name is because there is no carry generated in the process.

Algorithm for **No Carry Adder**:

```
function no_carry_adder(A,B)
    while B != 0:
        X = A XOR B, Bitwise-XOR of A,B.
        Y = A AND B, Bitwise-AND of A,B.
        A = X
        B = Y << 1, Multiplying Y by 2.
    return A
```

As you can see, the `while` loop executes those four instructions again and again until `B = 0`, and when `B = 0`, binary number stored in `A` is the answer.
Now the question was to find out how many times the `while` loop will execute before `B = 0` or `B` becomes zero.

If I have gone for the naive way i.e write the algorithm as it is described in any programming language like in `Python` it will give me an answer but it will be time-consuming if the number of bits in the binary string `A` and `B` is `> 500`.

So when you analyze some of cases, for example:

- **Case 1:** When both `A = B = 0`.
         In this case the number of times the loop iterates `= 0` as `B = 0`.
- **Case 2:** When `A != 0` and `B = 0`.
         In this case the number of times the loop iterates `= 0` as `B = 0`.
- **Case 3:** When `A = 0` and `B != 0`.
         In this case, the number of times the loop iterates `= 1` because after the first iteration, the value of `X = B` as when you do the `bitwise XOR` of any binary number with `0` the result is the number itself. The value of `Y = 0` because `bitwise AND` of any number with `0` is `0`. So, you can see `Y = 0` then `B = 0` as `Y << 1 = 0`.
- **Case 4:** When `A = B` and `A != 0` and `B != 0`.
         In this case, the number of times the loop iterates `= 2` because in first iteration the value `A = 0`, why because `bitwise XOR` of two same numbers is always `0` and value of `Y = B` because `bitwise AND` of two same numbers is the number itself and then `B = Y << 1`, after the first iteration, this case becomes **Case-3**. So, the number of iteration will always be `2`.
- **Case-5:** When `A != B` and `A != 0` and `B != 0`.
  In this case, the number of times the loop iterates `= length of the longest carry-chain`.

**Algorithm to calculate the longest carry-chain:**

- First make both the binary strings `A` and `B` of equal length if they are not of equal length.
- As we know the length of the largest carry sequence will be the answer, I just need to find the maximum carry sequence length I have occurred till now.
- I will iterate from left to right i.e. LSB to MSB and:

  - `if carry + A[i] + B[i] == 2` means that bit marks the start of carry-sequence, so `++curr_carry_sequence` and `carry = 1`.
  - `if carry + A[i] + B[i] == 3` means the carry which was forwarded by previous bit addition is consumed here and this bit will generate the new carry and length of carry-sequence will reset to 1 i.e. `curr_carry_sequence = 1` and `carry = 1`.
  - `if carry + A[i] + B[i] == 1 or 0` means carry generated by the previous bit resolves here and it will mark the end of the carry-sequence, so the length of the sequence will reset to 0. i.e. `curr_carry_sequence = 0` and `carry = 0`.
- Now if `curr_carry_seq` length is `>` than `max_carry_sequence`, then you update the `max_carry_sequence`.
- Answer would be `max_carry_sequence + 1`.

**Solution source-code in C**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<assert.h>

#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 100001

static int compute_loop_iteration(const char *const, const char *const);
static bool check_all_zeroes(const char *const);

int main(void) {
    int test;
    scanf("%d", &test);
    assert(test > 0 && test < 100001);
    while(test--) {
        char a[MAX_STRING_LENGTH],b[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
        scanf("%s%s", a,b);
        const size_t len_a = strlen(a), len_b = strlen(b);
        char *binary_string_A, *binary_string_B;
        binary_string_A = binary_string_B = NULL;
        if(len_a < len_b) {
            binary_string_A = calloc((len_b + 1), sizeof(char));
            memset(binary_string_A, '0', (sizeof(char) * (len_b - len_a)));
            memmove(&binary_string_A[len_b - len_a], a, (sizeof(char) * len_a));
            binary_string_B = calloc((len_b + 1), sizeof(char));
            snprintf(binary_string_B,len_b + 1, "%s", b);
        } else if(len_a > len_b) {
            binary_string_B = calloc((len_a + 1), sizeof(char));
            memset(binary_string_B, '0', (sizeof(char) * (len_a - len_b)));
            memmove(&binary_string_B[len_a - len_b], b, (sizeof(char) * len_b));
            binary_string_A = calloc((len_a + 1), sizeof(char));
            snprintf(binary_string_A,len_a + 1, "%s", a);
        } else {
            binary_string_A = calloc((len_a + 1), sizeof(char));
            snprintf(binary_string_A,(len_a + 1), "%s", a);
            binary_string_B = calloc((len_b + 1), sizeof(char));
            snprintf(binary_string_B,(len_b + 1), "%s", b);
        }
        int loop_count = 0;
        if(check_all_zeroes(binary_string_B)) {
            loop_count = 0;
        } else if(check_all_zeroes(binary_string_A)) {
            loop_count = 1;
        } else if(!strcmp(binary_string_A,binary_string_B)) {
            loop_count = 2;
        } else {
            loop_count = compute_loop_iteration(binary_string_A, binary_string_B);
        }
        printf("%u\n", loop_count);
        free(binary_string_A);
        free(binary_string_B);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

static bool check_all_zeroes(const char *const binary_string) {
    bool is_zeroes = true;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; '\0' != binary_string[i]; ++i) {
        if('0' != binary_string[i]) {
            is_zeroes = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return is_zeroes;
}

static int compute_loop_iteration(const char *const binary_string_A, const char *const binary_string_B) {
    const size_t limit = strlen(binary_string_A);
    int carry, current_carry_seq_len, max_carry_seq_len;
    carry = current_carry_seq_len = max_carry_seq_len = 0;
    for(int i = limit - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        carry += (binary_string_A[i] - '0') + (binary_string_B[i] - '0');
        switch(carry) {
            case 3:
                current_carry_seq_len = 1;
                carry -= 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                --carry;
                ++current_carry_seq_len;
                break;
            default:
                carry = current_carry_seq_len = 0;
                break;
        }
        if (current_carry_seq_len > max_carry_seq_len) {
            max_carry_seq_len = current_carry_seq_len;
        }
    }
    return max_carry_seq_len + 1;
}
```